# Hampson-Linde cycle: why does expansion need to be isenthalpic

Tags: thermodynamics

If I understand correctly, the fluid in the Hampson-Linde cycle goes through an isenthalpic (basically a free?) expansion. For ideal gases, T would remain the same. But, depending on the substance and the temperature, the fluid may cool down.
My question is: why enthalpic? If the work (of the expanding fluid) could be used, would that not (1) lead to a bigger cooling effect and (2) useful energy output?
(I'm a beginner, so the answer might be obvious...)

Comment: You are talking about the Joule-Thomson step in the process, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Are you familiar with the derivation of the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics?

Comment: In this case, would that be (all per unit mass): work + enthalpy[out] - enthalpy[in] + 1/2(speed[out]squared-speed[in]squared) = 0. Somehow I still don't get it. If work is done, then outgoing enthalpy goes down, meaning bigger cooling?

Comment: In the derivation, work is subdivided into two distinct parts:  Work to force mass into and out of the control volume, and shaft work.  The work to force mass into and out of the control volume (per unit mass) combine with the inlet and outlet internal energies to give the enthalpies in and out.  So these are accounted for.  And, in the flow through the orifice or porous plug situation in JT, there is no shaft work done..

Comment: Right, so what I'm thinking is, say, a turbine stage (mounted on a shaft) located at the orifice. Voila - nice shaft work and a cooler fluid. But surely I am making a mistake, I just can't see it?

Comment: I don't quite follow.  But it does make sense to me that, if you replaced the orifice with a turbine, you could cool the working fluid even more and, at the same time, extract some work.  If you're asking why they don't do that, I don't know.  I would have to study the details of the cycle more deeply.